# Ensure that page break does not intervene between a section heading and a list

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

Is there an easy way to ensure that a page break will not intervene between a `\section` macro (or another similar macro) and an `\itemize` environment (or another similar environment)?

I have used package `titlesec` to make `\section` look how I want it, but I wonder if there is something I could add to titlesec to ensure that there won't be a pagebreak between the section heading and the list.

Here is the problem code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\scshape}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{\parindent}{*2}{\wordsep}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10-14]

Words

Words

Words

Words

\section{Section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Words
    \item Words
    \item Words
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the default layout of `\section` from a `display`-style heading to a `runin`-style heading. And since you don't have any content following the `\section` other than a list, a page break occurs. You can conveniently issue a `\pagebreak` prior to `\section` wherever you have these odd cases. Or, an automated solution can be provided (with some finetuning required) by [`needspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/needspace):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec,needspace}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\scshape}
  {}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
  {\parindent}{*2}{\wordsep}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldsection}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{}{%
  \needspace{2\baselineskip}% Need roughly 2 lines available, otherwise issue a page break
  \oldsection
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10-14]

Words

Words

Words

Words

\section{Section}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Words
  \item Words
  \item Words
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! This seems to cause extra indentation, however. How can I eliminate that?

Comment: @NoahJ: It shouldn't, unless you have a spurious space somewhere.